# smtp 554 rejected - poor reputation

Tags: email, smtp, spam

My SMTP (e-mail server) do not send e-mails for 99% of the tries.

Log SMTP server hMailServer:

```
"SMTPD" 1092    17  "2012-02-09 12:55:20.328"   "173.44.33.116"     "RECEIVED: DATA"
"SMTPD" 1092    17  "2012-02-09 12:55:20.359"   "173.44.33.116"     "SENT: 354 OK, send."
"SMTPD" 572     17  "2012-02-09 12:55:22.031"   "173.44.33.116"     "SENT: 250 Queued (1.328 seconds)"
"SMTPC" 1076    298 "2012-02-09 12:55:23.312"   "216.69.186.201"    "RECEIVED: 554-m1pismtp01-002.prod.mesa1.secureserver.net"
"SMTPC" 1088    298 "2012-02-09 12:55:23.312"   "216.69.186.201"    "RECEIVED: 554 Your access to this mail system has been rejected due to the sending MTA's poor reputation. If you believe that this failure is in error, please contact the intended recipient via alternate means."
"SMTPC" 1088    298 "2012-02-09 12:55:23.328"   "216.69.186.201"    "SENT: QUIT"
```

But I am not blacklisted! My IP addresses are 173.44.33.116 and 173.44.33.117, if you want to check for yourself.

Why am I seeing this message error

`RECEIVED: 554 Your access to this mail system has been rejected due to the sending MTA's poor reputation. If you believe that this failure is in error, please contact the intended recipient via alternate means.`

when I'm not blacklisted?

How can I configure my SMTP to avoid receive this message and my e-mails can go to inbox folder and not spam folder?

Comment: duplicate of [Why am I seeing "554 - Sending MTA's poor reputation" when I'm not blacklisted?](http://serverfault.com/questions/358422/why-am-i-seeing-554-sending-mtas-poor-reputation-when-im-not-blacklisted)

Answer (score 4):

A lot of the anti-spam devices and software in use by mail systems these days leverage *private* IP reputation services. What's more, they frequently build their own reputation lists based on what each system sees themselves. Chances are you actually are on one of these private blacklists; or worse, behavior of your mailer has caused your system to be dropped into the *local* blacklist.

You may not be in any RBL list yet, but that doesn't stop the likes of Symantec or Microsoft from adding your IP anyway.

Comment: Precisely. No one can say "I'm not blacklisted". It's like saying "no one dislikes me!"

Comment: maybe it's like saying 'no one dislikes Microsoft'

Answer (score 1):

Clearly your email servers *are* blacklisted, on either a public blacklist you haven't checked or on peoples private blacklists.

Its worth remembering that the Internet is a network of computer systems and networks that, essentially, communicate with each other *by mutual consent*. The people you're getting this error from are perfectly entitled to refuse to accept email from your server for whatever reason they please. You're equally entitled to block them from accessing your website on a Tuesday because you don't like Tuesdays very much, or any other reason *you* choose.

As the rejection message says, you need to contact the person you're sending to by another method and ask them if they can help you sort out the problem. Also, it may be worth emailing postmaster at the domain in question (e.g. postmaster@example.com) - well run mail systems don't apply blocks to that address to allow people to write to the email system administrators to ask why their system is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

First job would be to do all Open relay, SPF(TXT), PTR, things.

Or maybe.. IP address 173.44.33.117, is listed here as pursuasivecampaigns.com misc.
(And so is .116)

http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check

http://www.five-ten-sg.com/mapper